# Temporary power

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm setting up a temporary power pole, but I can't find an answer to this question:  I only need 100 amp service, but finding a 100 amp meter base isn't very easy.  Can I install a 200 amp meter base, then have my main breaker at 100 amp?  From what I understand, the meter base can be higher amp than your main breaker, just not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 200 A capacity of the meter base and/or panel is the max capacity of that panel.  If you put a 100 A breaker to protect it, that will be fine.  You only create a safety concern if you put a breaker that has a GREATER capacity than the equipment it's going into.

For example you would NOT put a 200 A breaker in a 100 A panel.